# Click Event Not detected inside a Raphael Element

Tags: raphael

I created some shapes in Raphael Js and tried to bind the click event to those shapes.But,the click is getting detected only at the border/path line of that shape.below is a section of code
square = paper.rect(200, 200, 50, 50);

```
            // square.click(function() {
            //     console.log('clicked');
            // })
            $(square.node).click(function (evt) {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
```

Am not able to discern the cause.Please help

Comment: Sure you have a fill set on the element ?

Comment: No, there is no fillset on the element

Comment: Okay,After setting the fill on the element,it works fine. Thankyou @Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to click on the 'space' in an element, you need to give it a fill.

```
el.attr({ fill: 'red', opacity: 0.1 });
```

Note, if you want the background to show through still even with a fill, you could set it with opacity 0.0001 or similar and you would be able to click it still.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a more complete sample that shows the rest of the HTML on the page: when this happens it is typically an overlap issue. There is a DOM element that is sharing space with the Raphael canvas and might be intercepting the click events.